# should I do with docker-compose? when I have 2 project

Tags: docker-compose

I'm having 2 project

A {mysql, redis, rails}
B {mysql, redis, rails}

should I do

- create a docker-compose.yml file with a MySql, a redis, rails1, rails2
  or
- create 2 docker-compose.yml file with each is a Mysql, a Redis, rails

help me!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a docker-compose.yml file with your common services. And then create two project specific composer files which inherits the root composer file.

docker-compose.project.template.yml

```
services:
  mysql:
    ....
```

docker.compose.project.a.yml

```
services:
  mysql:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.project.template.yml
      service: mysql
    ...
```

Another option is to create a general project docker-compose.yml file and use environment variables to customize the behaviour.